# How to configure auto cleanup of Gradle Cache? - How to delete old incremental jars?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

We're doing incremental builds on our build server that generates snapshots that all such as "blue-sky-0.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" without any build number (same name for each increment).    Gradle is happily downloading the latest build and using it, but examining ~/.gradle/cache you can see all the various versions.

However, we ran into an issue with the Source Jars as IntelliJ is providing all the source jars without an indication of what is the latest.   We're deleting all the copies to get a single copy.

So, we're basically maintaining the local cache manually.

Questions:

1) Is there a way to configure gradle to just delete any old copies when it downloads a new jar?

2) Is their a better pattern for incremental builds?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Gradle cleanup:
There have been some significant improvements in 4.6 ([1](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#local-build-cache-directory-cleanup-is-now-time-based), [2](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/dsl/org.gradle.caching.local.DirectoryBuildCache.html)) and 4.10 ([1](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/release-notes.html#periodic-cache-cleanup), [2](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:gradle_user_home:cache_cleanup),[3](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:project_root:cache_cleanup)) so if you are using an older version maybe consider upgrading to them. They have introduced automatic cache cleanup. However, the time is not (yet) configurable for all the cases, and a relevant [issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7018) in their Github page has opened.